# Segfault on printing values from linked list (C)

Tags: c, loops, fault

fpI have no idea why this would seg fault, I close the files properly, I stay within the linked list for my loops, and yet when it gets to the for loop or the while fgets loop (one of the two) it seg faults. I have a very similar function that works perfectly and I modified this from that, but it doesnt produce the same output

```
static int wordMode(struct node *head, char* word)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    int count = 0;
    char* filecheck;
    char* tester;
    ptr = head;

    //print the lines
    for (ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next){
        if ( strcmp(ptr->fileName, filecheck) != 0 ) {
            filecheck = ptr->fileName;
            printf("=====================%s\n", filecheck);

            //if new file, open it and start printing
             FILE *fp = fopen(ptr->fileName, "r");
                char line [ 1024 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
                int counter = 1;
                while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, fp ) != NULL ) /* read a line */{
                     //check if the line number is in the linked list, if so add match
                     printf(" %d: %s", counter, line); /* write the line */
                     counter++;
                  }
                  fclose ( fp );
        } 
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `gdb` is your friend.  You should be able to run a stack trace on it and find out the exact line number it is faulting on.

Comment: I dont know how to use gdb for taking in the input of another command. For example if my file name is test, the way I used this is grep blah blah | test, if I do gdb test command then it simply says error enter valid input (because it doesnt have the grep std in)

Comment: Read the `man` pages for `gdb`, it will definitely help you in future development and debugging.  If you are using an IDE, then most of them have built-in debugging tools as well.

Comment: the first obvious problem is filecheck points to a random location when it is first used in this line: 'if ( strcmp(ptr->fileName, filecheck) != 0 ) {'  this is undefined behaviour which can/will lead to a seg fault event.  There are other problems, but this should get you started thinking about what the code is actually doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `filecheck` has not been initialised.

```
char* filecheck;
....

    if ( strcmp(ptr->fileName, filecheck) != 0 ) {
```

It needs to be set to something.

```
char* filecheck = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pointer to the `File *file` is not called fp. It is file. 
And also `fclose(fp)` should be `fclose(file)`

Comment: Sorry I have updated the code, that is not the problem!

Comment: In strcmp you are comparing pointer and a filename,, perhaps is that. But pointer filecheck is never initalized.